# Browser intermittently complains about Stack Overflow's SSL certificate

Tags: bug, ssl, firefox, safari

It's now happened several times lately that when I attempt to visit `https://stackoverflow.com`, Firefox gives me this page:

> **Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue**
>
> Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to
> stackoverflow.com because this website requires a secure connection.
>
> What can you do about it?
>
> stackoverflow.com has a security policy called HTTP Strict Transport
> Security (HSTS), which means that Firefox can only connect to it
> securely. You can’t add an exception to visit this site.
>
> The issue is most likely with the website, and there is nothing you
> can do to resolve it. You can notify the website’s administrator about
> the problem.

When I click the "Advanced" button on Firefox, this shows up:

> Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust
> this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for
> stackoverflow.com. The certificate is only valid for the following
> names: chat.sockets.stackexchange.com, qa.sockets.stackexchange.com
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

Safari also shows a similar page so, I don't think it's Firefox. Is this an issue with my computer or SO? If it's an issue with my computer, how can I fix it?

Note: It seems to happen temporarily. I try to visit SO, and it fails, but ~10 minutes later it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with this one, but I think you are not the only one, (see... euh oops, Thread has disappeared..., oh...! was this one, but sbd completely changed the Title...!), but *"has a security policy called HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS), which means that Firefox can only connect to it securely. You can’t add an exception to visit this site.*", hum, very good, that "explains" a lot for me, (using very old Versions of FF (FF55) and PM (PM26)), but you still get a -1 from me for not mentioning your FCI. ("Firefox" loosely mentioned in the middle of you Post "is not enough"...)

Comment: The error vaguely suggests that the page's contents attempted to fetch something over plain HTTP. If you can identify this resource when it happens (probably using your browser's development tools or similar) then we have something to go on.

Comment: @tripleee would that cause the entire page to crash? I would think that would just raise an error in the XHR or whatever. Either way, it seems odd that it would happen intermittently. I would note that it says the bad certificate is for `chat.sockets.stackexchange.com` or  `qa.sockets.stackexchange.com`

Comment: @chivracq you owe me +1. Whoever changed the title removed the Firefox bit, though the issue also applied in Safari.

Comment: Yeah, but again, could you mention your FCI (Full Config Info, => Browser Versions + OS) for both Browsers...? The behaviour you are describing is a known issue for all Sites using 'Let's Encrypt' Certificates (not "meant" for "professional"/heavy traffic Sites anyway, no comment...), but "normally" only affecting "older" Versions of FF (<FF52, I think) on all OS'es, + 'Safari' and all Browsers on some "older" Tablets running on iOS (not sure until which Version)... I often see it with PM v26.3.3 ('Pale Moon') + Win10, forked on FF26, with Patch-Level = FF47, while FF55 is still "immune"...

Comment: ok, I'll add it when i get back.

Comment: @chivracq: Firefox 114.0.1 (64-bit) & Safari 15612.2.9.1.30 running on MacOS 10.15.7 Catalina. Anything else?

Comment: "*Anything else?*" => Nope, that's fine, I think... But you should add that Info to the Question itself, not only as a Comment... Then well, I don't know about 'Safari' but your 'FF114' looks pretty "current" to me, and the "known issue" I mentioned is/was only with pretty old Versions of FF, I don't think 'FF114' would be affected..., and/or other Users would be reporting it also...